# What is the effect of Disable Link parameters found in nearly all Web Deploy examples?

Tags: iis, web-deployment

I have a simple question that is hard to find any documentation on. All examples I find for deploying Web Deploy packages include the following arguments: `-disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension` but there is no explanation to be found what these do or why this is being done. I'm having issues with files in use even though I'm using the `-enableRule:AppOffline` rule so I'm wondering because `-disableLink:AppPoolExtension` is not there it's failing to stop the app pool properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **–disableLink** arguments indicate that you don't want to replicate application pools, virtual directory configuration, or Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificates on the destination server.

**AppPool**:

Includes the application pool associated with the specified Web application.

**AppPoolExtension**:

Includes the application pool associated with the specified Web application.

**CertificateExtension**:

When an SSL certificate hash is detected in the IIS configuration, includes the associated certificate. Enabling this link extension will include all certificates associated with your Web application and the certificate path information in each certificate. These certificates can be HTTPS certificates from a local certification authority or signed certificates from external certification authorities like Verisign.

**ContentExtension**:

Includes the contents of a virtual directory in an operation whenever a virtualDirectory configuration element or VirtualDir metabase path is detected.

**FrameworkConfigExtension**:

Includes the configuration in the Machine.config or root Web.config files if location tags occur in those configuration files that are specific to the Web site. The Machine.config and root Web.config files that correspond to the Framework version of the Web application will be included.

and by using the **-enableRule:AppOffline** Web Deploy takes an application offline by using the "AppOffline" rule.

you could refer this below link for more detail:

[Taking an Application Offline before Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing)

[Deploying Web Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages)

Comment: Thank you for the addition, indeed the documentation I was looking for. I am using the AppOffline rule already. Do you happen to know what the max duration is an Application Pool gets to shutdown? For now I have resolved the issue by doing longer retries and retry intervals.

Comment: @IvanL The way it works is if Web Deploy detects that a change needs to be made on the destination server, it will automatically drop a blank App_Offline.htm file into the root of the application folder. When ASP.Net detects that a file by the name of "App_Offline.htm" exists, it will automatically bring down the app domain hosting the application. When the publishing process is completed, the App_Offline.htm file will be removed and the site will be online again. what is your application pool state is it start or stop?

Comment: Yes this I know and I've seen that this happens however the app pool doesn't seem to shut down immediately. I've noticed it takes up to 40 seconds for the app pool to shut down and release the files in my case. So having added high retry intervals and retries fixed this for me but I'm interested if IIS itself imposes a max timeout for the app pool